# How to access d3 point coordinates after transform

Tags: d3.js

How do I access d3 point coordinates after transformation? I realize the x and y attributes of the point do not appear to actually change for instance

```
d3.selectAll(".node")
    .each(function(d){console.log(d.y);}
```

returns the y values before transformation

Comment: You could use `.getBBox()`.

Comment: This returns y = 0 and x = 0

Comment: Can you show us your full code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the code is not there so i will explain this with an example:

Imagine you have and svg with a group like:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("id", "root")
                                     .attr("width", 200)
                                     .attr("height", 200).append("g");
```

Lets draw a circle in it:

```
 //Draw the Circle in the g group
 var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
                          .attr("cx", 30)
                          .attr("cy", 30)
                         .attr("r", 20);
```

Lets give the group a translation of 100, 200

```
svgContainer.attr("transform", "translate(100,200)");
```

So now post translation the circle center point will appear @ 130, 230 i.e. *circle's cx will be (30 + 100)* 
*circle's cy will be (200+30)*

If you check the cx and cy of the circle it will show as 30, 30.

So in order to find the position after the transform do the following:

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
    .forEach(function(d){
    var point = document.getElementById('root').createSVGPoint();//here roor is the svg's id
    point.x = d3.select(d[0]).attr("cx");//get the circle cx 
    point.y = d3.select(d[0]).attr("cy");//get the circle cy
    var newPoint = point.matrixTransform(d[0].getCTM());//new point after the transform
    console.log(newPoint);
});
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/b3gem191/2/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but how do I modify this to return positions for nodes in the example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550